# Python: sort list of strings in order that they appear in another string

Tags: python, string, sorting

I am looking for a way to sort a list in order of appearance in another string, so that the the follow code

```
thelist = ["a", "b", "c"]
thestring = "b c a"
```

will be able to be sorted into

```
["b", "c", "a"]
```

as that is the order that each of the list objects appear in the string.

How would I go about achieving this? Would it be possible to use the sorted function with certain param to easily achieve this or something else?
Thanks.

Comment: Just use `thestring.split()`, *instead* of sorting `thelist`?

Comment: You could try `.sort(key=lambda c: thestring.index(c))`, but that won't deal with repeats nicely

Comment: Yes I would need to be able to sort where there are multiple, any other way?

Comment: @Vatec this is a non-deterministic sorting when characters are repeated! (or in other words - you can't...)

Comment: @Vatec: multiple *what*? Repeated elements in `thelist`? Or repeats in `thestring`? In which case what position *wins*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn your string into a map:

```
indices = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(thestring.split())}
```

then sort using that map:

```
sorted(thelist, key=indices.get)
```

This allows for values from `thestring` *missing* in `thelist` as well as vice-versa. This also works correctly for repeating elements in `thelist`.

Demo:

```
>>> thestring = "b c a"
>>> indices = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(thestring.split())}
>>> sorted(['a', 'b', 'c'], key=indices.get)
['b', 'c', 'a']
>>> sorted(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b'], key=indices.get)
['b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a']
>>> sorted(['a', 'a', 'a'], key=indices.get)
['a', 'a', 'a']
>>> sorted(['a', 'e', 'b'], key=indices.get)
['e', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: Thank you, this would work except thestring will not always be seperated by spaces, it could be "ycyby" which needs to produce ["c", b"]

Comment: @Vatec: then use `{c: i for i, c in enumerate(thestring)}`, the exact integer values don't really matter.

Comment: @Vatec: Perhaps in future you could be a bit more clear on such requirements?

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am new to python and stackoverflow I will be more clear next time

Comment: Perfect answer!! (Windows server 2012 R2; Python 3.7)